# php insert into mysql table from object

Tags: php, mysql

Please, I've got a table in an array I want to update with object with matching schema in php. query:

```
REPLACE INTO entries ( mail, name, gender, age, ip, t, code, v, ansvers ) 
VALUES ( '$entry->mail', '$entry->name', '$entry->gender', '$entry->age', '$entry->ip', '$entry->t', '$entry->code', '$entry->v', '$entry->ansvers' )
```

I'd like to know if there is any simple way to specify variables without having to create query string using loop and retrieving object/array variable keys or typing everything manually like this.
for example, if I rename `$entry->mail` to `$entry->mail2` then query will do:

```
REPLACE INTO entries ( mail2 ) VALUES ( `$entry->mail2` )
```

if needed, $entry can be changed to any data structure.

thanks.

Comment: Use ORM such as [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com)

Comment: Are both examples pseudocode, or real? Both seem susceptible to SQL injections, and `VALUES ( \`$entry->mail2\` )` is invalid.

Comment: $entry is created beforehand in php and performs checks and escapes. due to number of security and validity check its in whole new file. the first example is real  code, string in query(""). the second is just pseudocode to show what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is truly a 1:1 correspondence from the object to the table you could do this to generate the query:

```
$query = "REPLACE INTO entries (" . 
   implode(',', array_keys(get_object_vars($entry))) .
   ") VALUES ('" . 
   implode("','", get_object_vars($entry)) .
   "')";
```

Comment: thanks. i hoped for some kind of auto function, but this is simple enough and i need to return get_object_vars($entry) for other functions anyway.